# Message from Azure Blob Storage to Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to figure out if Azure Blob Storage has similar functionality to Amazon S3. An S3 bucket can be configured in a way, that when new object is created, bucket sends message to SQS. I'm wondering if Azure Blob Storage is able to do the same with Azure Service Bus (which is kind of similar to SQS, correct?).

The only resource I've found so far, which mentions something similar is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview, but there is no Azure Service Bus on the right side. I know I can use Functions as a proxy, but I'm interested in direct connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service bus(I think you compare service bus with SQS and SNS in AWS) don't have the ability to subscripe to Blob storage events. Event Grid(the link that you reffered to has Service bus support on the roadmap but no date is confirmed.

I think your best choice is Azure Functions(or Logic app if you don't want to write code) that has a blob Storage trigger to catch events and do action X.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function.

Or wait a litte for event grid but you still get that "proxy" part.

Comment: is there any thing changed since then, now?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use logic apps/ event grid and you can add trigger directly from azure blob storage (https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/azure-service-bus-now-integrates-with-azure-event-grid/) . Another option would be to add blob trigger with azure functions and write the code to do whatever action which you are looking for .